# What does wp_term_taxonomy.parent reference?

Tags: database, taxonomy, terms

My initial thought was that it referenced another taxonomy (i.e. an FK from `wp_term_taxonomy.parent` to `wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id`). ORMs like Corcel are [built under this assumption](https://github.com/corcel/corcel/blob/2.7/src/Model/Taxonomy.php#L58). However, I've [done some digging](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89691/has-parent-field-in-the-table-wp-term-taxonomy-has-term-id-or-term-taxonomy-id) and most information seems to indicate that it actually references `wp_terms.term_id`.

In the case of Corcel, I think that this coincidentally works - WordPress will set the `term_id` and the `term_taxonomy_id` to the same value. If you've messed with the data, or applied your own imports / migrations, you might not get this same behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress doesn't use actual FOREIGN KEY constraints in MySQL. So, *technically*, `wp_term_taxonomy.parent` is merely an integer. However, what you've found is correct: it refers to a term in `wp_terms` by its `term_id`. But, as you've also noticed, the `term_id` and `term_taxonomy_id` should always be the same.

The reason they both exists is historical. Prior to WordPress 4.2, it was possible for taxonomy terms to belong to multiple taxonomies. So you could have a single term in `wp_terms` that corresponded to multiple rows in `wp_term_taxonomies`. WordPress 4.2 changed this so that terms can only belong to a single taxonomy. You can read some of the background on this change in [this Make post from 2015](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/02/16/taxonomy-term-splitting-in-4-2-a-developer-guide/).

These days you should only be using `term_id` to refer to terms programatically, and since a term's parent is also a term, the parent value refers to another term by its `term_id`.

Ideally the `parent` property would just be in the `wp_terms` table, but the existing structure will likely remain in place for backwards compatibility reasons.